# Firefox: Interfacing with code

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk

I found a library online that I wish to take advantage of for an application I am writing.

The source code is here: https://dxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mozilla/security/manager/ssl/nsISiteSecurityService.idl

How would I reference that library? The following doesn't work.

```
var { nsSiteSecurity} = require('/security/manager/ssl/nsISiteSecurityService');
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
nsSiteSecurity = require('chrome').Ci.nsISiteSecurityService
```

This will give you access to that function.